# Algebraic Structure of $(\mathbb{C},\cdot)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

> Determine which algebraic structure is $(\mathbb{C},\cdot); z\in \mathbb{C} ,|z|=1$ where $\cdot$ is multiplication in $\mathbb{C}$

Can we derive all of the axioms: associativity, identity element
,Inverse element and commutativity straight from the fact the $\mathbb{z}$ is a field? as the fact that all $z$ in the set ($|z|=1$) does not affect those axioms and therefore $(\mathbb{C},\cdot); z\in \mathbb{C} ,|z|=1$ is an abelian group?

Comment: If we denote the set of these $z$ by $S$, we have to verify that for $z\in S$ it's inverse is also in $S$ (field axioms only guarantee there is an inverse somewhere in $\mathbb C$), and that the multiplicative identity is in $S$ (rather clear). Also, to be safe, one should check that $S$ is closed under multiplication.

Comment: @Wojowu this mean to prove that the set is a sub-group.

Comment: This is a subgroup indeed!